# Add dynamic html without using compose inside the View

Tags: aurelia

I need to add an html div element inside a custom component(footable).
Since the component is constructed at run time, I am not able to use compose anywhere in the html, therefor I must add my elements using jQuery.

Any ideas how can I add the below and bind to a ViewModel's method?
footable event:

```
'postinit.ft.table':function(e,ft){
   $('.footable-filtering .form-inline').append('<div class="form-group"><a
   href="#" click.delegate="refreshNow()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa
fa-refresh"></i></a></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably come at it a different way. I'd use jQuery's `.on` handler to attach a listener to the `.footable-filtering` element, seeing as it seems that's present from the start;

```
'postinit.ft.table':function(e,ft){
    $('.footable-filtering .form-inline').append('<div class="form-group"><a
        href="#" click.delegate="refreshNow()" class="btn btn-primary refreshButton"><i 
        class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a></div>');
}

$('.footable-filtering').on('click', '.refreshButton', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.refreshNow();
}
```

This is untested - but *should* work.

**Edt** - It's also worth saying that combining Aurelia and jQuery in this way isn't ideal - but as you're using jQuery anyway to create the element it's use is passable.

Comment: Thanks it worked!
As for the jQuery an dAurelia, I agree but I couldnt bother creating an aurelia bridge plugin for footable now.